# SQL: return true/false if multiple values exists or not in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with two columns that are foreign keys (think in userID(int) : orderID(int) for example), and I have to know if orders 2, 3, 4, 5 exists for a user ID, in a where clause of a big query.

I need to optimize my database

```
SELECT table1.myrow FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.myrow = table2.myrow
AND 1 IN (SELECT myRoww from table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.myrow)
AND 2 IN (SELECT myRoww from table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.myrow)
AND 3 IN (SELECT myRoww from table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.myrow)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
 AND (SELECT * from mytable) IN (SELECT myRoww from table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.myrow)
```

How can I determine if my multiple value list exists for an ID? the rows i'm requesting are relations that consist in only a table with two foreign keys.

My relations:

[image: relational model]

Need to know if CONVOCATORIA_SECTOR have X relations for a CONVOCATORIAS(id_bdns_Conv)

Comment: Can you please include the actual tables you are using along with some sample data?

Comment: Yes give me a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by grouping by userid and a condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select userid
from tablename
where orderid in (2,3,4,5)
group by userid
having count(distinct orderid) = 4
```

This will select all the `userid`s for which there exist the `orderid`s 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: I don't understand the having you added

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to make it complete.

Comment: The HAVING clause guarantees that the distinct orderids for each user are 4 and since the WHERE clause restricts the orderids to 2,3,4,5 then these 4 are the ones that exist for the user.

Comment: This not solves my problem because I need to add this to "where" clause for selecting or not the rows.

Comment: You can add it  to a WHERE clause like: `WHERE somecolumn IN (<query here>)`.

Answer (score 0):

as an ugly answer, you can concatenate both columns like this

```
AND (SELECT column1||column2 from mytable) IN (SELECT column1||column2 from table2 WHERE table2.id = table1.myrow)
```

is not the best way but it works